# Can I customize ff-find-other-file to switch between tests and implementations?

Tags: python, emacs

Whenever I have to edit C++ code, I use `ff-find-other-file` to switch back and forth between header and implementation files.  Can I use it for Python files to switch back and forth between implementations and tests?  For example, if I'm in `foo.py`, I'd like to be able to switch to `foo_test.py`.

Answer (score 5):

You actually want to set `ff-other-file-alist` (and possibly also `ff-search-directories`). These variables are automatically buffer-local, so you can safely set them in a mode hook.

`cc-other-file-alist` is a pre-configured mapping for C/C++ files which is just the default value for `ff-other-file-alist`.

To handle the reverse mapping from the test back to the implementation, you would add a second entry, so the alist would look like this:

```el
'(("_test\\.py$" (".py"))
  ("\\.py$" ("_test.py")))
```

The reverse mapping needs to go first in this case, as the rules are processed in order and `.py` matches both filenames. If they were the other way around you would still go from `foo_test.py` to `foo_test_test.py`, and so on...

See this related question for some more information and an example:

[If I open doc.foo file, I want emacs to look for and open doc.bar file in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958672/if-i-open-doc-foo-file-i-want-emacs-to-look-for-and-open-doc-bar-file-in-the-sa/10958810#10958810)

For your case, you could use:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)

(defun my-python-mode-hook ()
  "My python customisations."
  (setq ff-search-directories '(".")
        ff-other-file-alist '(("_test\\.py$" (".py"))
                              ("\\.py$" ("_test.py")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .emacs rule setting cc-other-file-alist, e.g.:

```
(setq cc-other-file-alist
  `(("\\.py$" ("_test.py"))))
```

Comment: This works for translating foo.py into foo_test.py, but it translates foo_test.py into foo_test_test.py.  Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find much documentation on any of this stuff.

Comment: Look at the comments in find-file.el