# If I open doc.foo file, I want emacs to look for and open doc.bar file in the same folder

Tags: emacs, elisp, auctex

Specifically this problem arises when working in LaTeX (auctex) for me, but I think it must have a general emacs solution.

To every doc.tex file, I have an associated and oft-edited doc.sty file in the same folder.

Is there a way that whenever I open the doc.tex file I can have emacs open the doc.sty file in that folder? I'm not proficient at all in elisp, so something very simple---it doesn't need to be robust code: it can work on the assumption that both files are named doc.* and that both exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the commentary for:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `find-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

It's not precisely what you asked for, but it is a built-in solution for opening related files. Just bind a key to `ff-find-other-file` (or `ff-find-related-file` if you prefer that alias), and you can switch back and forth between the two files easily.

In particular, see:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `ff-other-file-alist` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `ff-search-directories` <kbd>RET</kbd>

So something like this:

```el
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'my-latex-mode-hook)

(defun my-latex-mode-hook ()
  "My LaTeX customisations."
  (setq ff-search-directories '(".")
        ff-other-file-alist  '(("\\.tex$" (".sty"))
                               ("\\.sty$" (".tex"))))
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'ff-find-other-file))
```